# Can I require a generic parameter to have generic parameters?

Tags: java, generics, syntax

I would like to write a class that looks like this:

```
public class SomeClass<T<?>> {
    T<String> someField;
    // ...
}
```

But this is not valid Java. Is there any way to tell Java that the generic parameter `T` must be a class that accepts one generic parameter, such as `List`, `ArrayList`, `Supplier` or `Consumer`.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: You will probably need to share the problem you're trying to solve. What you're trying to do is technically impossible, and you don't want a simple "it's not possible" answer.

Comment: No, but you can instead specify some terms your class T has to fulfill, such as : `T extends X implements Z, W`

Comment: Sounds like you need a marker interface, which all valid type parameters of T should implement.

Answer (score 3):

In a word, no, there isn't. You could limit `T` to extend some class or implement some interface, but you can't limit it to being a generic class itself.

Answer (score 2):

There are no *higher kinded types* in Java. You'll need Scala (or Haskell or Rust) for that sort of thing.